# Associative array issue with '=>'. It '>' treats from 1st '=>'as closed bracket

Tags: php

Associative array problem. In Apache 2.4.9  the php version 5.5.12

I defined

```
$age = array( "Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", );
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```

The output result:

```
"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", ); echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old."; ?>
```

I looked at the 'View Page Source'  and  found it treats '>' from 1st '=>' as closed bracket

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: You shouldn't be outputting actual code. Something is amiss.

Comment: did you forget the <?php

Comment: If it's treating `>` as a bracket then it thinks your PHP is HTML probably. Like @goto said, did you forget `<?php` ?

Comment: could also be issue if using short tag `<?` if `short_open_tag` is off in your php.ini.

Comment: Are you requesting the file through a web-server, does the address start with `http`?

Comment: It was my discrepancy  the way I run script in browser.

Comment: from notepad++ used Run and it user URL

Answer (score 0):

The code is in HTML mode, not PHP code

And you have an open HTML tag above this code, most likely php with out the question mark.

```
<?php 
$age = array( "Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", );
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.<br/>";
?>


<php


$age = array( "Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", );
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```

Output form above code

Peter is 35 years old.
"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", ); echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";

---

**If that is not the case** then your server is Handling PHP as HTML.

If I have this PHP

```
<?php 
$age = array( "Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", );
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.<br/>";
?>
```

And change the file extension from .php  to .html, I get the same result.

"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", ); echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";

---

Add a Handler for PHP

In .htaccess or Apache configuration add:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Or in your site control panel go to Apache Handlers

```
Handler: php5-script 
Extension(s): .php
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize it was me of not being attentive.

From Notepad++  I used from title menu  'Run'-'Launch from Firefox' and it

treated it as Html page file:///C:/wamp/www/sandbox/assoc_arrays.php

I should run http://localhost/sandbox/assoc_arrays.php .
 When I did it yilded correct result.

Thank you all for the quick response. Assuming I run script correctly the answers are very good. I'm newbie to Php and this form is excellent resource.